# How to read two inputs of different data types in one space separated line in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I wanted to know id this could be done in a single line:

```
a,b = input().split()
```

These two inputs `a` and `b-->` where `a` is a string and `b` is an integer, 
by default splitting them makes the integer value a string too.
such as `a= 'WHALES'`, `b = '2'`.

How can I make it `'WHALES' 2` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach. Using a list comprehension.

**Demo:**

```
a,b = [int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in input("Enter").split() ]
print(a, b)
print(type(a), type(b))
```

**Output:**

```
WHALES 2
<type 'str'> <type 'int'>
```